# Render tags string returned by function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a function that builds an HTML table and returns the code as a string. I'm calling this function from within renderUI and outputting as HTML but the HTML is not getting parsed, I only get string as plain text in output. Do I need to add anything to my function call?

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    fluidRow(
        column(width=3),
        column(width=6, htmlOutput('table')),
        column(width=3)
    )
)
```

```
server <- function(input, output) {

tables <- data.frame(c("exmpl1", "exmpl2"), c("abc", "def"))

        output$table <- renderUI({
            create.table(tables)
        })
}
```

```
create.table = function(tables) {
  rowCount <- c(1:nrow(tables))
  htmlTbl <-
    paste(
      "tags$table(
             tags$tr(
               tags$th('Col1'),
               tags$th('Col2'),
               tags$th('Col3')
             ),"
    )
  for (val in rowCount) {
    htmlTbl <- paste(htmlTbl,"tags$tr(
      tags$td(checkboxInput('check",val,"', NULL)),
      tags$td(tables[",val,", 1]),
      tags$td(tables[",val,", 2]))"
    )

  if (val != length(rowCount))
      htmlTbl <- paste(htmlTbl,",")
  }

  htmlTbl <- paste(htmlTbl,")")

  return(htmlTbl)
}
```

Comment: at a glance I think `htmlTbl <- eval(parse(text=htmlTbl))` right before your return statement might do the trick.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!